# How can I change the font of the JFrame`s title?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm using SeaGlass L&F. I tried `setFont(font)` but nothing happened to the JFrame's title. What should I do?

Comment: Frame title bar is OS-depended and cannot be modified. You can only turn it off and try to implement your own one, which can be customized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame title bar is OS-depended and cannot be modified. You can only turn it off and implement your own one.

**To remove the OS-dependent decorations:**

```
jFrame.setUndecorated(true)
```

This should be invoked before you show this frame (eg. before call to setVisible(true));

Then implement your own TittleBar with any font or look you need.

Comment: I tried it and saw a frame with nothing. But i think it could be a good start to make my own TitleBar. Thank you.

Comment: Yes exactly, now you need to implement your own TittleBar